# Pi2 SSH Connection refused

Tags: ssh, connection

To preface, I'm new to Linux so likely doing something very dim and may not know the right terminology... We also have a pretty extensive network set up at home, with 30+ devices with assigned IP addresses, so I'm not sure if something there is causing the problem.

That said, I've just set up a new pi2. Setup seemed to go OK, though I wasn't able to get the WiFi USB working. However, I do have an active internet connection through ethernet and a local IP address and have removed the WiFi dongle. I've double checked that ssh is enabled through the advanced config menu.

Using terminal on a mac, I'm unable to ssh into the pi. I've looked through similar posts and haven't been able to find a solution.

When I try to SSH in, using -vv, I receive the message below:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.1.43 [10.0.1.43] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.1.43 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.0.1.43 port 22: Connection refused
```

I would add that when I try to ping the pi, I don't think this is working correctly, as I get the response below:

```
PING 10.0.1.43 (10.0.1.43): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
etc... until I quit the terminal window
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Going nuts with this and need to get it fixed before the SO gets home later today!

---

I've confirmed I'm running wheezy.

The output for ethernet from the `ifconfig` is as follows:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:27:eb:04:13:27 
 inet addr:10.0.1.43 Bcast:10.0.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
 RX packets:10197 errors:0 dropped:76 overruns:0 frame:0
 TX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
 RX bytes:1073617 (1.0 MiB) TX bytes:73618 (71.8 KiB)
```

---

One more bit of info which I think may be helpful. From the pi, I'm able to ping one of my devices with no errors, but when I attempt to ping the mac I'm using to ssh I receive an error that says "destination host unreachable."

I'm also able to ping the pi from my mac terminal successfully using the ip address 127.0.0.1, however unable to ssh using this address.

Comment: Nothing will work until the ping works.  Why do you think the Pi has IP address 10.0.1.43?

Comment: How is the mac connected to the network and the Pi?

Comment: You asked the right question... So freaking annoying--Comcast's new Xfinity modem sets up several guest networks and at some point the wifi on my mac switched over to the guest network. SSH working fine now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Lack of connectivity caused by the pi and mac not being on the same wifi network. Comcast's new Xfinity modem sets up several guest networks and at some point the wifi on my mac switched over to the guest network.